# FancyBox2 official demo - YouTube doesn't load first time in IE9

Tags: youtube, internet-explorer-9, fancybox-2

I have noticed specific behavior of FancyBox2 Demo in IE9, maybe someone could tell, what causes the problem or how it could be fixed. I mean youtube link, which uses fancybox-media class. When I open demo by using link 'standalone version' on http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples, youtube link works properly and window with movie opens immediately, but when I clean the browsing history and then open site by pasting http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/ into URL bar, youtube window doesn't open the first time and succeeds the next time. It makes the example source code used in any different site couses the same problem. Maybe explanation is simple but I'm not very familiar with jquery and any tip will be usefull.